# python 2.7 multiprocessing. pool.apply_async inside another pool.apply_async

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pool

python 2.7 multiprocessing. `pool.apply_async` inside another `pool.apply_async`

I have 2 modules A and B.
Module 'A' declares a pool of size 100 and with `pool.apply_async,` a function 'BX' from module 'B' is called.
The function 'BX' in module 'B' creates another pool of size n, and using its `pool.apply_async` another function is called.

This problem that am facing right now is that the execution process is getting stopped/exit just at the point of declaring pool in module 'B'. ie while declaring 2nd pool in module 'B' which is inside 1st pool of module 'A'.

Any solution on executing pool.apply_async inside pool.apply_async?

Comment: what's the point of thread in a thread, and as you say, multiprocessing, you're not working with threads, you're working with processes :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like what I'm showing below.  Note that I'm using my own fork of `multiprocessing` (called `pathos`) because it provides better serialization, enables you to run from the interpreter, and is more efficient in the creation and maintenance of pools.  However, the workflow should be roughly the same as shown here:

```
>>> import pathos as p
>>> tp1 = p.pools.ThreadPool(100)
>>> tp2 = p.pools.ThreadPool(50)
>>> import itertools as it
>>>
>>> res = tp1.amap(tp2.amap, it.repeat(lambda x:x**2), [range(10)]*5)
>>> ans = res.get()
>>> [v.get() for v in ans]
[[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]]
```

Note that `amap` in `pathos` is `map_async` in `multiprocessing`. If you just wanted `apply_async`, that's `apipe` in `pathos`.  Then to shut things down:

```
>>> tp1.close()
>>> tp2.close()
>>> tp1.join() 
>>> tp2.join()
>>> # pathos has an additional shutdown step to clear the pool cache
>>> tp1.clear()
>>> tp2.clear()
```

So, with the equivalent of `apply_async`, it'd look like this:

```
>>> tp1 = p.pools.ThreadPool(100)
>>> tp2 = p.pools.ThreadPool(50)
>>> tp1.apipe(tp2.apipe, lambda x:x**2, 10).get().get()
100
>>> tp1.close()
>>> tp2.close()
>>> tp1.join()
>>> tp2.join()
>>> tp1.clear()
>>> tp2.clear()
```